# Redirect form input from a servlet to another form

Tags: java, javascript, forms, servlets

I have a form created by a servlet which is supposed to fill out a text input field from a search. So the form is like this :

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" readonly="true" value="" /> <button href="/searchServlet />
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, it opens up another form , which does the search and displays the results as list from which the user can pick any result. The picked result id populates some hidden fields in the form. Now do I get those hidden fields data in "form1"? Is there some Javascript for that purpose? Or can I redirect input from one servlet to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is indeed your friend here. Give the input a name as well and let the button open a dialog by [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="text1" readonly="true" />
  <button onclick="window.open('/searchServlet');">search</button>
</form>
```

Then in the HTML generated by `/searchServlet` and its JSP in the dialog, you can use [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) to get the parent window and then from there do the usual `document` stuff as if you're sitting in the parent window. Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
<button onclick="window.opener.document.form1.text1.value='1'; window.close();">1</button>
<button onclick="window.opener.document.form1.text1.value='2'; window.close();">2</button>
<button onclick="window.opener.document.form1.text1.value='3'; window.close();">3</button>
```

Of course you'd like to abstract/refactor the verbosity/duplication away in some function.